# Не устанавливается PyXML

Tags: python, gcc, python-2.x, xslt, python-2.7

Доброго времени суток. Требуется произвести XSLT преобразование на Python 2.7, для этого необходимо установить библиотеку PyXML. Но при установке появляется ошибка

```
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Причем gcc я установил (MinGW).
Вопрос, как исправить ошибку? Возможны альтернативные способы XSLT преобразования. Делаю все под Windows 7.

Comment: Уважаю археологов. 2004 год! MinGW тогда точно был, но зачастую рекомендовалось его не использовать. Попробуйте собрать gcc под cygwin'ом. Ключик -mno-cygwin -- оттуда. Но более подробной инструкции я дать просто не смогу. На крайний случай можете использовать и python 2.7 под cygwin, если будут проблемы с использованием пакета под native-python

Comment: Есть причины, по которым lxml для xslt в Питоне не используете? По воспоминаниям, лучше pyxml избегать.

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался.

Просто в MinGW были убраны некоторые опции, такие как `-mno-cygwin`. Проблема решается комментированием требуемых опций в файле `cygwinccompiler.py`.